# How to notify spring boot app when new record is inserted into db table?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, spring-boot

I have requirement where spring boot app needs to send notification using websocket (STOMP) in real time when new record is inserted in DB table. Insertion of the records will be done by third party apps.

Is there any way to get db events/records in realtime using spring boot framework ? if yes , please suggest implementation.

Note: I am new to java and Database concepts.

Comment: You will probably have to poll the database.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks. any reference or example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089601/database-polling-using-spring-integration